# How do I shift voltage levels?

Tags: arduino, level-shifting

I want to use an [RF12B](http://www.hoperf.com/rf_fsk/rfm12b.htm) to communicate over radio with an Arduino, but the transceiver is rated at 3.3 V. I hear I need to use a voltage level shifter, but what do these look like and where can I find a schematic to help me hook it up?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708/i2c-3-3-to-5-0-v-conversion http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/622/bi-directional-step-up-and-step-down-3-3v-5-etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what direction the signals are going to.

- If the 5 V device is going to drive a signal on the 3.3 V device, use a simple resistor division.
- If the 3.3 V device is going to drive a signal on the 5 V device, you could use two inverters with the last stage tied to 5 V. However, this requires four resistors and two transistors, which is quite an expense. You could also try out the implementation as shown in [Sparkfun's breakbout board](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/Level-Converter-v10.pdf).
- If the signal is bidirectional (I²C), maybe something in [this appnote on page 10](http://www.kip.uni-heidelberg.de/lhcb/Publications/external/AN97055.pdf) will work (seems similar to what Sparkfun is using).

Answer (score 9):

Microchip has [this document](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/groups/techpub_sg/documents/devicedoc/en026368.pdf) with 19 tips about mixing 3V and 5V parts in a circuit (not just level shifting).
The tips:

> 1. Powering 3.3V Systems From 5V Using an LDO Regulator
> 2. Low-Cost Alternative Power System Using a Zener Diode
> 3. Lower Cost Alternative Power System Using 3 Rectifier Diodes
> 4. Powering 3.3V Systems From 5V Using Switching Regulators
> 5. 3.3V → 5V Direct Connect
> 6. 3.3V → 5V Using a MOSFET Translator
> 7. 3.3V → 5V Using A Diode Offset
> 8. 3.3V → 5V Using A Voltage Comparator
> 9. 5V → 3.3V Direct Connect
> 10. 5V → 3.3V With Diode Clamp
> 11. 5V → 3.3V Active Clamp
> 12. 5V → 3.3V Resistor Divider
> 13. 3.3V → 5V Level Translators
> 14. 3.3V → 5V Analog Gain Block
> 15. 3.3V → 5V Analog Offset Block
> 16. 5V → 3.3V Active Analog Attenuator
> 17. 5V → 3V Analog Limiter
> 18. Driving Bipolar Transistors
> 19. Driving N-Channel MOSFET Transistors

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of ways to to voltage level shifting, depending on how fancy you want to get. Just to name a single manufacturer, [Texas Instruments](http://focus.ti.com/paramsearch/docs/parametricsearch.tsp?familyId=705&family=analog&uiTemplateId=NODE_STRY_PGE_T) has a whole section devoted to mixed-voltage interfacing between different protocols. You can almost guarantee that there's a chip that will fill your needs.

Alternatively, as pointed out in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/546/voltage-level-shifter/547#547), SparkFun makes a [small board](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8745) that will probably be the easiest solution to implement. Your radio appears to use SPI, which should be workable with that board.

Comment: The Texas Instruments link seems to be (effectively) broken.